# Changing projection of a netcdf

Tags: r, netcdf, map-projections, reprojection-error

I have netcdf files of daily temperature and precipitation data
How is it possible to Change projection of a netcdf?

I have tried to doing this using raster function to read the files
and reproject them with projectraster?

Code_used

```
a <-raster(file.nc)
cr1<-"+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
 projectRaster(a, cr1,res =  0.04166667)
```

ERROR_

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"character"’
In addition: Warning message:
In min(dim(to)[1:2]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Answer (score 3):

The help for `projectRaster` gives this usage:

```
Usage:

     projectRaster(from, to, res, crs, method="bilinear", 
                  alignOnly=FALSE, over=FALSE, filename="", ...)
```

if you call it with two unnamed arguments, they get matched to `from` and `to`, and `to` is:

```
  to: Raster* object with the parameters to which 'from' should be
      projected
```

if instead you name the second argument, this should work:

```
  a_project = projectRaster(a, crs = cr1, res =  0.04166667)
```

because now the second argument is matched as the `crs` argument.

BUT if you just want to transform a gdal-compatible data set then you can use `gdaltransform`, either from the command line or via the function with the same name from the `gdalUtils` package.

Comment: Do you have an example of implementation?

Comment: it asks for gdal to be installed... i cant find this